# Get HTMLPurifier 4.5 to allow only one tag

Tags: htmlpurifier

HTMLPurifier by default allows a lot of tags that I don't want to allow. According to the documentation you have to add definitions like this:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $def->addAttribute('a', 'target', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(array('_blank','_self','_target','_top')));
}
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to remove all tags that comes from `HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();`.

For example the HTML `<div>Sometext</div>` will keep the DIV tag using the above initialization code.

How can I set HTMLPurifier to only allow `<strong>`, `<a href="*">` and `<p>`?

Comment: I feel that HTMLPurifier may have become slightly over architected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: "*According to the documentation you have to add definitions like this*".

Unless something fundamental has changed since the last time I checked the library (a year ago, about), that's not quite true - that part exists for if you want to teach HTML Purifier *new* attributes that it isn't natively aware of. For example, if you wanted to teach your HTML Purifier to accept non-standard `<font>` attributes, like `align=""`, you'd need to alter the raw HTML definition.

However, if your whitelist consists purely of regular HTML elements (and yours does!), you just need to use the `$config` object:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array(
    'strong','a','p'
));
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array(
    'a.href'
));
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

That should work. Are you running into problems with that constellation?

(Check out this document, too: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/INSTALL )

Comment: Thank you. I've done it similarly to that before, but I thought the most recent version had changed their API a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found was to use the old way of configuring HTMLPurifier;

```
if($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array(
        'strong','a','p'
    ));
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array(
        'a.href'
    ));
}
```

How this works in relation with the HTMLDefinition I don't know. Maybe they have a compatability layer.

The biggest concern I have is that this is not using the `$def` variable returned - and that the changes I do to the config is not cached.

Comment: I'm confused why you have that `if` in there at all; check out the end of http://htmlpurifier.org/live/INSTALL - you should be able to set those configuration values without a raw HTML definition get.